# Why is the background color of my UIButton not affected in state config?

Tags: uibutton, ios9, states

I am trying to configure `UIButton` disabled state using attribute inspector 'state config.'   How can I configure the background color for the disabled state?

Comment: I asked for background not for text color ?

Comment: Your title asks "Why is ... ?", but the details ask "How can I configure ... ?" - which question are you asking to have answered?  The title and description should both be seeking the same kind of answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@IBAction func buttonStateChanged(sender: UIButton) {
        if(sender.selected){
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
        }else{
            sender.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)
        }
    }
```